# Log file for X hours in NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have .net 7 console app, I would like to log data into folder for every day and create sub files for every X hours ( from appsettings)

Ex : \15Dec2023\1200-1600.log

My Configuration is :

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="C:\LOGS_ADIALER\${date:format=ddMMMyyyy}\${custom-log-name}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${message} ${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

I have tried to create a Custom layout renderer like this :

```
[LayoutRenderer("custom-log-name")]
public class CustomLog : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        if(hour <= 4) 
            builder.Append("0000-0400");
        else if(hour <= 8)
            builder.Append("0400-0800");
        else if(hour <= 12)
            builder.Append("0800-1200");
        else if(hour <= 16)
            builder.Append("1200-1600");
        else if(hour <= 20)
            builder.Append("1600-2000");
        else
            builder.Append("2000-2400");

    }
}
```

For testing, I have hard coded the logic.

Registered it like this is :

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    // configure Logging with NLog
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
    loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
    LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(ext =>
    {
        ext.RegisterLayoutRenderer<CustomLog>();
    });
});
```

It works on application start but it fails to create a new file

Comment: You must register any custom NLog extensions upfront, and not after loading NLog-configuration. It is recommended to enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and check [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) when troubleshooting NLog. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for the comment, When i checked the logs , I realised , the config was also changed later